# Running H2 script tools

Tags: grails, h2

I'm running grails 2.3.3 with an 'in-memory' H2 database in a Windows environment.

I'm trying to use the command line tools such as Script in order to take backups of the data table.

I've located the jar file:

```
C:\Program Files\springsource\grails-2.3.3\lib\hsqldb\hsqldb\jars\hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
```

Here is the command I am trying:

```
java -cp hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar orgh2.tools.Shell
```

But I get the error:

```
    'Error: Could not find or load main class orgh2.tools.Shell'
```

Here is an explanation of the dB configuration. I have two Dbs as defined in the config file DataSource.groovy they both use user sa with a blank password at the moment.

Here are the key lines in the DataSource file:

```
dataSource {
            pooled = true
            driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
            username = "sa"
            password = ""
}

hibernate {
            cache.use_second_level_cache = true
            cache.use_query_cache = false
            cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}

   dataSource {
    dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:h2:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
    }

dataSource_publish {
    dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
    url = "jdbc:h2:/dbmak/devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT10000;
                    AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
}
```

Because this is an 'in-memory' configuration I am unable to change the sa password as it gets automatically reset to a blank value when the grails application is restarted.

I found the java jar in : grails-2.3.3\lib\com.h2database\h2\jars.

So my command now is: 
java -cp h2-1.3.173.jar org.h2.tools.Shell

If I do this I then am asked interactively to input a set of responses in order to get into the target database - that is: "

```
"Driver", "Database", "Login User and finally Password.
```

The password is blank and requires me to press RTN twice before a connection is achieved.

I have been able to successfully go into ONE of my Dbs (jdbc:h2:/dbmak/devDb) but not the other and then was able to run an SQL command.

However , if I try to access the dB: jdbc:h2:devDb I get an error:

'SQL Exception: Wrong user name or password'.

Which is strange as I am able to access both dBs with the same user/password via a dbconsole web session.

Finally, what I'm ultimately trying to do is to have a set of scripts to extract the contents of all each individual db tables into separate files (possibly using the -script option to run a separate file. Ideally the command line should do this without any interaction - I have tried to use the -url -driver -user and -password input parameters to remove this interactive part. But I am unable to get any of these options working yet.

Welcome any suggestions?

-mike

Comment: looks like you forget a dot after org, org.h2.tools.Shell

Comment: @user3584190 I meant to add - Yes that makes more sense - but I still get the 'Could not find error or load main class' error. If I download a separate h2 installation then the command works for that separate h2 system. Perhaps the tools are not loaded with the grail springsource installation? Can I load them independently or is there another way to extract the current contents of the in-memory database?

Comment: @mikek You want to run queries against the DB? Search "h2 database console grails"

Comment: hsqldb and h2 are 2 different database engines. You need to use h2 not hsqldb. Another weak point in your question: you can only access the in-memory database from another java process provided you named the in-memory database and that the jvm created this in-memory db has not disconnected from it.

Comment: @Christian I found the java jar in : grails-2.3.3\lib\com.h2database\h2\jars. and I have been able to run an SQL session in a project dB. However, there are still some issues - see my initial question above which I have added to.